# Why have the vertically passed air gates been abolished?

Tags: rules, air-racing

In the past (up until the new 2014 season), a Red Bull Air Race track consisted of 3 different kinds of gates, requiring different fly through procedures:

1. Pylon pairs to be flown through horizontally.
2. Pylon pairs to be flown through vertically.
3. Single chicane pylons to be crossed on alternating sides (with irrelevant roll angle).

But in the new season in 2014 there don't seem to be any gates of the 2nd kind anymore.  All gates apart from the single chicane ones are to be passed in horizontal position. But while there seem to have been quite a few rule changes after the 4 year break, in order to equalize some technical aspects of the planes and to generally increase the safety, I couldn't find any information about the removal of the vertical gates in particular.

So **why were the vertically passed pylon pairs abolished?** Is this also connected to increasing safety? If yes, then in which way were those gates less safe than the horizontal ones? If not, then what else is the reasoning for their removal?

Comment: I hope Red Bull Air Race is on-topic. But since Formula 1 is, I don't see a reason why it shouldn't. If yes, someone with sufficient reputation might be kind enough to add the `red-bull-air-race` tag.

Comment: Welcome to Sports.SE!  This question is definitely on-topic here, although you might get a better response at [Aviation.SE](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/).